# SwiftUI: Error when init data with a function in ObservableObject model view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an issue with fetch data and return for a variable which is declared in a model view:

```
struct ExploreDataSource: Decodable {
    var places: [Place]
}

class ExploreViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var dataSource: ExploreDataSource

    init () {
        dataSource = fetchDataSource()
    }

    func fetchDataSource () -> ExploreDataSource {
        var dataSourceRes = ExploreDataSource(places: [])
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: APIEndPoint.getExploreURL())!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, err in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let resData = try decoder.decode(ExploreDataSource.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    dataSourceRes = resData
                }

            } catch {
            }
        }).resume()
        return dataSourceRes
    }

}
```

Error:

`'self' used in method call 'fetchDataSource' before all stored properties are initialized`

in `init` function line.

Answer (score 0):

you do this :

```
init () {
    dataSource = fetchDataSource()
}
```

to fill your dataSource -> and in fetch... you are using self before (!) you fill dataSource. This is not allowed. 
You can either declare dataSource as Optional or fill it empty in init.

In a class all variables of the class itself have to be filled before you can use "self".